Why does auto refresh does not work on power query
I have created a power query which is pulling data from .xlsx which is present in My documents. I want the power query to refresh data every 2 mins, I have set up the same on power query -> right click -> properties. But when data changes in the file present in My documents path the power query is not refreshing even after 5 mins. Is there anything missing? Thanks in advance.
Below is the image :


Have got this working. I had to delete all .tmp files and refresh and try again.
